# Identity Server: Access tokens/items set in AuthorizationProeperties in ExternalLoginCallback on the client

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

#### Question

I have an identity server implementation that is being used by a number of applications in test and production. I am currently working on a new feature, where the client application using the identity server can perform Azure service management REST api calls. For this, it needs a token. I can generate this token, store it and even access it in the `AccountController` in the identity server.

My issue is figuring out how to send this to the client. I don't think this token belongs in the claims for the user. So I tried to add it as part of `AuthenticationProperties` as a token, but I cannot seem to access it in the client. Should I store it in a session like this SO user did [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41519132/312219)? There is one answer to this question, but that does not seem right (I even tried it out of desperation!)

#### Relevant sections of code

Generate the token

```
var resource = "https://management.azure.com/";

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
     Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                       // Acquire the token for the resource and save it
                    }
                }
}
```

Restore it in `AccountController`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
      string resource = "https://management.azure.com/";

      // snip
      result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

      // snip

      AuthenticationProperties props = null;
      var tokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
      var id_token = info.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
      if (id_token != null)
      {
          tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = id_token });
      }

      if (result != null)
      {
          tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken { Name = "management_token", Value = result.AccessToken });
      }

      if (tokens.Any())
      {
          props = new AuthenticationProperties();
          props.StoreTokens(tokens);
      }

     // snip
     // Can I access these "props" on the client? I even tried adding it to `Items`, no luck.
      await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.UserId, user.DisplayName, provider, props, additionalClaims.ToArray());
}
```

So, my question, is this the right way go about it? If so, how do I access the authentication properties set? Or should I try saving this in the `Session`? If so, how do I store it in the client's session?

Any pointers would help. Thank you!

Comment: any luck with finding a solution @k25 ? I'm dealing with a similar problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552223/922713

Comment: @AmirChatrbahr I posted an answer indicating how. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post an answer so that people wanting the same can benefit.

A token cache can be implemented to achieve this. [This](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth) repository explains how.

Pay special attention to the `AdalDistributedTokenCache` linked [here](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Services/AdalDistributedTokenCache.cs)