# ADB2C refresh token challenge not working on Chrome Android

Tags: google-chrome, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the standard OIDC .NET library to make a challenge request to ADB2C. From my understanding, this automagically attempts the sign in with the refresh token in cache and gains an authorization without re-asking for credentials.

This seems to work absolutely fine, except on 1 browser - Chrome on Android. No matter what I try, this browser seems to to lose the refresh token, so after around 1 hr, it starts asking for credentials again. I have cross checked this on Chrome web/mac, edge, IE, safari, FF and they all behave as expected to maintain a constant logged in state.

Any ideas? This should be browser independent from what I understand, but maybe I'm missing a trick?

---

**Update**

This seems to be similar behaviour even when accessing a web app protected by AD. Again, Chrome loses the refresh, but other browsers are fine.

---

**Update**

I see this in Fiddler when trying to access the site after the expired token

### Chrome

Set-Cookie: x-ms-cpim-csrf=XXX; domain=auth.mywebsite.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly

### Edge

Set-Cookie: x-ms-cpim-sso:mytenant.onmicrosoft.com_0=XXX; domain=auth.mywebsite.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly

So yes there is a difference, but why and how to fix?

Comment: Are you using MSAL.js in the front-end?

Comment: No, using this in a .NET core mvc app and using this library https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp with the default in memory token cache.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the issue with SameSite cookies in Chrome that causes he cookies to not be sent as you expect. Here's a few pointers to help you out:

- [How To Prepare Your IdentityServer For Chrome's SameSite Cookie Changes - And How To Deal With Safari, Nevertheless](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/)
- [Upcoming Browser Behavior Changes: What Developers Need to Know](https://auth0.com/blog/browser-behavior-changes-what-developers-need-to-know/)

But I think first of all you should verify if this is a SameSite issue, by using a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to capture the traffic and verify that the cookies are indeed lost. Do compare in Fiddler your different browsers and see if there's some differences.

Do try to login using a incognito mode,  so that you start with no cookies in the browser. Then you should see the cookies being set both by your identity provider and your application.

In Fiddler you can under the Filter tab enable the first item in the picture to flag responses that set cookies, to make it even easier to detect when cookies are set.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

[image]

Comment: I think you may be right that is something to do with this. I have actually already implemented the first link you mention, but this seems to be happening on newer versions of Chrome (v84 +) and that article seems to mention iOS and safari hacks mainly. There seems to be little info around on how to resolve this when its Chrome losing the cookie. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Would you know the exact steps required to do this, and what particular cookie I would be looking for?

Comment: updated my answer, hope that makes this an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the identity domain is setting the cookie and it is path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly. If I now delete the AspNetCookies (to mimic an expiry) and go to a secured end point in my app, it does challenge the identity and I can see it is setting the cookie fine. I will re-test this in a couple of hours to see if this is still the case.

Comment: Great! Do you use HTTPS for all traffic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220454/discussion-between-raj-and-tore-nestenius).

Comment: Still struggling to get an answer to this. Any thoughts? I am wondering if it is not a samesite issue now, but more a server side issue, but I cant seem to find the right combination of settings to make this all work.

Comment: Is the cookie sent at all to the Chrome browser? can you verify that? do you see any differences beteween browser here?

Comment: Updated my response above