# User is authenticated after OpenId Connect (AAD) but Unable to find access token

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, access-token, openid-connect

I am trying to find the access token from AAD after user is authenticated from OpenId Connect. **It is a web application integrated with AAD OpenId Connect. I need to get the access token to call another API that uses the same AAD.** Here's what I've tried:

1. Clone [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/) sample code.
2. In Startup.cs file, add the following block of code:

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor();

       services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
   {
       sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   })
   .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
         .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
         {
             options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
             options.ClientId = "<<client-id>>";
             options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
             options.SaveTokens = true;
             options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
             options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

         })
   .AddCookie();
   services.AddMvc();}
   ```
3. In `HomeController` class, I added a private variable called `httpContextAccessor` and also set it in the constructor.

   ```
       private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
       public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
       {
           _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
       }
   ```
4. In the `HomeController` class, I added some code to access the access token.

   ```
    public IActionResult Index()
       {
           if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               var attempt1 = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
               var attempt2 = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
               var attempt3 = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
               var attempt4 = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorziation"];
           }
           return View();
       }
   ```

But all of them return either empty or null. Did I miss anything?

I've looked at this following posts for reference:
[How to refresh access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852138/how-to-refresh-access-token) 
[How to get access token from HttpContext in .Net core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768774/how-to-get-access-token-from-httpcontext-in-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `SaveTokens` to true in OpenID Connect configuration:

1. Clone that code sample
2. Keep the `Startup.cs` , you don't need to add `.AddOpenIdConnect` part , `AddAzureAd` extension method would help add Azure Active Directory Authentication to your application.
3. Modify the `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs` in `Extensions` folder :

   ```
   public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
   {
       options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
       options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
       options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
       options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
       options.SaveTokens = true;  // set to true 
   }
   ```
4. Then you can get the ID token from `httpContextAccessor`:

   ```
   var idToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
   ```

But the access token is still null . The sample shows how to use the OpenID Connect ASP.NET Core middleware to sign-in users from a single Azure AD tenant , that means you can get the `ID Token` which  is sent to the client application as part of an OpenID Connect flow and is used by the client to authenticate the user. Please refer to document : [ID tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) .

While `Access tokens` enable clients to securely call APIs protected by Azure . Please refer to document : [Azure Active Directory access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) .

If you want to get the access token for accessing resource which protected by Azure AD , you should use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)(Azure AD V1.0 endpoint) to obtain the token , see code sample(especially [use `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` to acquire access token](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L66)):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Or use [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) if you are using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint .

Comment: Using your instructions step 1 - 4 works. Already got the token!! Thanks!!