# How to get new access token by using refresh token in AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (ASOS)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I am using React as client and Web API core for back end interaction.
For Authentication we are using Token based authentication using **AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (ASOS)**.

I have to implement refresh token scenario where on expiration of access token we use refresh token (returned by ASOS) to get new access Token.

I know one way to achieve by calling method on client is in AXIOS interceptor like below.

```
httpPromise.interceptors.response.use(undefined, err => {
  const { config, response: { status } } = err;
  const originalRequest = config;

  if (status === 401) {

    var refresh_Token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'));
    fetch(globalConstant.WEB_API_BASE_PATH + "authtoken,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
      },
      data:{grant-type:"refresh_Token",refresh_token:"refresh Token ....."
    )
    ....other logic to set new access token and make call again to existing 
    request.
   }
})
```

I want to done it in **WEB API Core  side**, so that in middle ware or in authentication pipeline it detects access token expiration and return new access token. The glimpse of WEB API code is like below.

```
Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
.... some code
    serives.AddAuthentication(o =>
     {                    
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                    
    })
    serives.AddOAuthValidation()           
    serives.AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
    {
        options.ProviderType = typeof(AuthorizationProvider);
        options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider(new SecurityService());
        options.TokenEndpointPath = "/authtoken";
        options.UserinfoEndpointPath = "/userInfo";
        options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
        options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
    });
..some code
}
```

The links i followed [How to handle expired access token in asp.net core using refresh token with OpenId Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032851/how-to-handle-expired-access-token-in-asp-net-core-using-refresh-token-with-open) and https://github.com/mderriey/aspnet-core-token-renewal/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get token details like access token,access token expiry time and refresh token etc. on OnAuthorization() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327048/how-to-get-token-details-like-access-token-access-token-expiry-time-and-refresh)

Comment: yes this link could be one of the way to achieve this , but if somebody have another way he/she can share.