# How to get token details like access token,access token expiry time and refresh token etc. on OnAuthorization() method

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I want to eject a logic that if access token is expired then generate refresh token on onAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) method in **ASP.NET WEB API Core**.

But i am not able to find a way to get token details.Basically how to get token details like expiry , refresh token from **AuthorizationFilterContext**.

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var user = context.HttpContext.User;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var test = context.;
        ..code to get refresh token...
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you implement token authentication? Do you use with header `access_token` or `Bearer` token?

Comment: Bearer token in authorization

Answer (score 3):

For token authentication, you could retrive the token from header and then decode the token.

Try code below:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    //var token = context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault().Split(" ")[1];
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token);
    var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
}
```

Comment: on Read Token it is throwing exception , i am using ASOS for creating token.

Comment: @SandeepRasgotra What is `ASOS`? Share us the code which creats token.

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323188/how-to-get-new-access-token-by-using-refresh-token-in-aspnet-security-openidconn?noredirect=1#comment99277068_56323188

Comment: I think it is OAuth Authentication scheme.

Comment: It is OpenID connect server Token(ASOS).